# DataBase Design, History table for page

Tags: database

I am looking for a design for my database...
I have machines: M1,M2,M3...Mn and each macine has a status (active,on hold, disabled etc). I need a history table of each time tha machine changed his status, and which user changed the status. I wonder how to do it.

```
table1
ID, MachineName, MachineStatus

table2
ID,OldStatus,NewStatus,Timestamp,UserID
```

or is there any better idea?

Comment: Well - if you want to keep history yourself (some database systems gives you tools for it), you do not actually need to store the new status, because you can always get changes based on history (next, previous) and current active value.

Comment: This sounds more of a kind a question that will fit http://programmers.stackexchange.com/